# Lot of pinned objects created in .Net app running on windows ce 7

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a .Net application which reads a lot of data from unmanaged environment every 25 mili seconds.

When I run this application for some hours let's say 25 hours, I get `MemoryoutofException` .
I have enabled performance monitor statistics which generates a stat file for my application.

In that file I see  Pinned Objects counter has been increased a lot it is `23467892`.
I read that lot of pinned objects will make memory fragmented.

I have the following method which I use to read data:

```
public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            uint BytesTransferred;
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* pByte = &(buffer[offset]))
                {
                    if (!ReadFile(hDSP, pByte, (uint)count, &BytesTransferred, 0)) // returns TRUE on success
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }                   
                }
            }

            return (int)BytesTransferred;
        }


[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        private static unsafe extern bool ReadFile(
                                        IntPtr hFile,
                                        byte* lpBuffer,
                                        uint nNumberOfBytesToRead,
                                        uint* lpNumberOfBytesRead,
                                        uint lpOverlapped);
```

In my `Read` method as far as I understand everything will be cleaned as soon as we return from the method.

Can someone explain/help me in understanding about which code is creating pinned objects and why they will not be unpinned ?

Comment: If you run a simple app that does nothing but call this method, do you still see the same issue?  How have you determined that this method is the problem?